# RadListView - how can I fire a 'tap' event programmatically

Tags: nativescript, radlistview

Got a RadListView and I'd like to fire off a 'tap' event via the program.

Can this be done?

i.e. a 'tap' on a list-item.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try configuring the tap event to call a function, and then just calling the function yourself?

Comment: Yes I thought of that. But the problem is that the tap event makes references to views inside the layout - and I don't have access to them at time of call (constructor).